# Publishing a VB.NET Winform Application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, publish, publishing

I have a windows form application that I need to publish, I just need some advice on what would be the best way to publish an application to a server so that multiple users can access it using a short cut on their desktop and without having to actually install the application on their local machines.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may run into CAS problems. It is better if users download code to their machines. Then you talking "ClickOnce"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71baz9ah.aspx